# How to make a reusable Angular 6 function for a click event without calling it in the ts file

Tags: angular

So I have this function for scrolling to an anchor element on the page when you click a button. You pass in the id of the section you want to scroll to in the function

This is the button that clicks using that function passing in the "gallery" id:

```
(click)="scrollToElement('gallery')"
```

Then in the component TS file that has the button in it:

```
scrollToElement($element): void {
    let anchor = document.getElementById($element).offsetTop - 100;
    window.scrollTo({top: anchor, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

How can I import this function from a service or something without having to write the full function into each component TS file that is using that (click) function.

For example, I just want to say:

import { ScrollToElement } from '@shared/services/scrollToClick.service';

And then I don't have to add any more code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add scrollToElement function in your ScrollToElement service and inject your service in your component

```
constructor(public scrollToElementService: ScrollToElement) {}
```

after which you can add in your template this

```
(click)="scrollToElementService.scrollToElement('gallery')"
```

Comment: This looks like the type of thing I'm looking for. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: can you show code how were you do it? make sure you added public in constructor

Comment: What should the service file look like? When I add it in the constructor like in your example it says something about a shadowed variable?

Comment: can you past here your ERROR message?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best place where you can leverage `Directive`. YOu don't need to have in any ts file. Keep your component ts file clean.

### track-scroll.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input , ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[track-scroll]',
  exportAs : 'trackScroll'
})
export class ScrollDirective {

    constructor(public el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { 

    }

   @Input("track-scroll")
   private name;

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    checkScroll() {
       this.scroll();
    }

   scroll(){
       console.log("scoll started");
       let anchor = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop;
       window.scrollTo({top: anchor, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
   }

}
```

Just use `track-scroll` Directory in the html.

> Note it just the reference, you may change your per your requirement.

Here is the working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-box

Comment: Does this directive account for the fact that the clicked element (the button) is not the same as the scrolled element?

Comment: This looks like something else. I need a global function that I can call when clicking a button basically.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with this design. I have created sample `directive` which can be control by separate `button`.  Demo is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-box